# Halyard - How to use --password-command option?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard, aws-ecr

About [Halyard](https://github.com/spinnaker/halyard/blob/master/docs/commands.md),
I want to use `--password-command` option to refresh Amazon ECR Authorization Token. If you have experience of using this option, please teach me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, the below worked for me.

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add my-ecr-registry \
 --address https://< Your ECR Endpoint> \
 --username AWS \
 --password-command "aws --region us-east-1 ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://'"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! I have another question: Does the clouddriver container has `aws` command installed?

Comment: Yes indeed. As I'm able to run the aws command inside the clouddriver pod .

Comment: Hi @alok I install Spinnaker from Helm Chart, but AWS CLI is not avaliable on halyard pod. On CloudDriver is ok. Do you have any ideas whats is wrong?

Comment: yes, aws cli is not installed on halyard by default I believe. If required, you can access the container as root and install it. However, if you are trying to configure ECR using --password-command, you won't need aws cli to be installed in halyard pod.